# Use a Column From a Code Table for the X-axis values on a bar chart

Tags: r

I have a bar chart which I made in ggplot2 which has gender variables like 0, 1, and 2 on the x axis.  Here is a sample of the data

```
Gender
1
1
1
1
0
0
0
0
2
2
2
2
```

I also have a code table that has information on the gender of the patients.

```
Code   Description
0      Male
1      Female
2      Unknown
```

I want to map it so the bar chart produced has the descriptions of the coded variables on the x axis instead of just the coded variables.  My professor wants me to map the codes after the creation of the bar chart to save on run-time, rather than converting all the codes in the beginning. Thanks!

Comment: Assuming you first table is data, and the second is data2: `data <- merge(data, data2, by.x = "Gender", by.y = "Code", all = TRUE); data$Gender <- as.factor(data$Description)`. Then plot. Your professor is wrong that this will add any run-time.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming table with gender information is t1 and with description is t2.
You can use names.arg argument of barplot function to solve your problem.

```
barplot(table(t1),names.arg =unlist(t2$Description))
```

However, you will need to make sure that description is in correct order.